# Lo que no puede ser, no puede ser, y además es imposible

Tags: significado

¿Cómo explicarías a un extranjero el significado de nuestra frase "**Lo que no puede ser no puede ser, y además es imposible**"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En el último mensaje de [este post parece estar la solución](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1498775&langid=24) (y más arriba en portugués). Desconozco a quien atribuir la cita, si al torero o al sacerdote *Charles Maurice de Talleyrand*

> La frase se atribuye al matador de toros Rafael Gómez Ortega "El Gallo" (1882-1960). En este pleonasmo quería rematar una redundancia: si una cosa no puede ser es que no puede ser, pero si existiera la más mínima posibilidad de que pudiera ser, en ese caso, sería imposible. [...] Actualmente se suele utilizar cuando algo es totalmente inviable.
>   Según la guía "Saber frases célebres" de Sopena la frase exacta es: "Lo que no pué ser, no pué ser, y además es imposible".

Comment: Siempre la he oído atribuída al Gallo y la explicación me parece correcta.

Comment: Esta frase me la ha dicho mi madre toda mi vida cada vez que yo le pedía algo que ella no podía conseguir. Independientemente de quién la dijera por primera vez, a mi me parece una frase cargada de la sorna y sentido del humor que existe en la manera de hablar en el sur de España, donde se tiende a adornar el lenguaje con el fin de ser un poco más divertido. Me parece, en cambio, una falta de respeto, o incluso a una gran ignorancia, atribuirla a la falta de cultura.

Comment: @Rafa Se ha quitado. El autor del mensaje se refería al torero ;).

Comment: Yo entendí que se refería al torero, y no a la gente que usa la frase

Comment: @AlexBcn: Lo sé, y me parece mucho suponer que este señor tuviera que ser un inculto. A mi no me gustan los toros, ni los toreros especialmente. Solo es que no creo correcto publicar aqui una definición basada en suposiciones bastante peregrinas. Todo esto, sin acritud, como diría el político aquel. :)